# Change text from h5 element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a element to show the page number / total of pages something like this:

> Pag: 1/6

This is what I have, I draw an entire HTML template with jQuery, is too much code so here is an example of what I do **(THIS CODE IS FOR PAGE 1/1)**:

```
var html = ""; //Here I draw my html code
html += '<td>';
html += '<h5 id="p1" class="text-right">Pag: ' + div + '/' + total + '</h5>';'
html += '</td>';
A lot of code.... and finally...

//I have 4 div (a total of 4 pages) so this is the reason of why I'm doing this:
var p = "div" + div.toString();
$('#' + p).html(html); //The final result is: #div1, #div2... etc
```

For page 2 I do the same but at the end I do this **(Pag 2)**:

```
var pag = "Pag: 1/2";
$('#p1').text(pag);
```

With this I change the h5 from page 1 (1/1 now is 1/2).

At this part everything its ok, but when I try to do the same thing for page 3 and 4 the text do not change, so my question is what could be the problem? Because I'm doing exactly the same thing for page 1 and 2 and works but in page 3 and 4 not, however here is what I do in **PAGE 3**:

```
var pag1 = "Pag: 1/3";
var pag2 = "Pag: 2/3";
$('#p1').text(pag1);
$('#p2').text(pag2);
```

As you can see this it's supposed to work, here is the function from where I draw the html:

```
$('#go').click(function () {
    div++;
    total++;

    if (div == 1)
        drawPage1(); //div and total = 1, h5 id="p1" Pag: 1/1
    if (div == 2)
        drawPage2(); //div and total = 2, h5 id="p2" Pag: 2/2
    if (div == 3)
        drawPage3(); ////div and total = 3, h5 id="p3" Pag: 3/3
});
```

What could be the problem of why this work in page 1 and 2 but not with 3 and 4? Thanks in advance.

Comment: console errors?

Comment: I have one but it's not about my function, but maybe this error is breaking all my js file in some point, let me try to solve it and see if solve this problem

Comment: Was that, some function was breaking my code before execute the function drawPage3(), so what can I do now? Delete the question? Answer what I do and mark like correct answer or what?

Comment: You can add an answer and mark it correct so others can learn from it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some function was breaking my code before the functions to draw page 3 and 4 were executed, the solution... read what the console was trying to say me.